# Configure an SSL connector for Tomcat, invoked by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ssl

I have a web app that runs under Tomcat when invoked through Netbeans. I'm trying to get it to run under eclipse.

The application runs but one of its web service calls fails with a message about a "handshake error". I've read different things about configuring an SSL connector for Tomcat to use, but I haven't gotten it working.

My immediate confusion is over the password(s) used for the certificate file and the certificate key file. I have the following connector at the moment:

```
    <Connector 
        SSLCertificateFile="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\csi_keystore.jks" 
        SSLCertificateKeyFile="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts" 
        SSLCipherSuite="RC4-SHA:HIGH:!ADH:!SSLv2:@STRENGTH" 
        SSLEnabled="true" 
        SSLPassword="psw1" 
        SSLProtocol="all" acceptCount="100" disableUploadTimeout="true" 
    enableLookups="false" executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxThreads="200" 
    port="443" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
```

And the following parameters being passed to Tomcat when running from Netbeans:

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true 
-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -server -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:NewSize=256m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\csi_keystore.jks" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=psw2 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="psw2"
```

Looking at the Tomcat documentation, I don't see the "SSLCertificateFile" and "SSLCertificateKeyFile" parameters in the examples I've got; are those accurate? What would the password be?

The documentation has an example including the parameters "keystore" and "keypass"; are those equivalent? Or preferred? Do I still need the key file and its password?

=== EDIT ===

Ok, I now understand that JSSE and APR are different implementations of SSL communications used by Tomcat, and that the configuration for each one is different. I am fairly sure we're using JSSE; the Netbeans configuration is

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\csi_keystore.jks" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=thePassword
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\jssecacerts" 
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword="thePassword"
```

added to the command line to execute the server (along with other parameters), and that looks like the JSSE parameters to me. So I put the following connector into server.xml:

```
<Connector 
    SSLEnabled="true"
    clientAuth="false" 
    keystoreFile="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\jre\lib\security\csi_keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="changeit" 
    maxThreads="200" 
    port="443" 
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" 
    scheme="https" 
    secure="true"
    sslProtocol="TLS"
    enableLookups="false" 
/>
```

But I don't see anything in there about the 'trustStore' or its password. Are those parameters also supposed to be in the server.xml? Or do you see something else I'm doing wrong?

I've turned on the verbose debugging (`-Djavax.net.debug=all`); at the point of the exception that I get are the following lines:

```
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C C5 D8 0A 7E   A5 D1 18 87 5A D6 EE EB  ............Z...
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 36
0000: 14 00 00 0C C5 D8 0A 7E   A5 D1 18 87 5A D6 EE EB  ............Z...
0010: 7D D4 BE 23 3C DB 78 99   10 43 94 45 10 09 20 8A  ...#<.x..C.E.. .
0020: C7 41 74 B0                                        .At.
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 36
[Raw write]: length = 41
0000: 16 03 01 00 24 5A 3F 83   45 A2 AA 61 7E F6 11 2D  ....$Z?.E..a...-
0010: 43 9D 15 A7 46 D7 FC 6B   F5 F2 26 BB 3E 35 D5 ED  C...F..k..&.>5..
0020: 0D 3F 81 84 6B BF 12 69   48                       .?..k..iH
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 15 03 01 00 02                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 2
0000: 02 28                                              .(
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-4, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
DEBUG:[22:01:36] Could not close WebServiceConnection
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1977)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1093)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1090)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
  at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection.getRequestOutputStream(HttpUrlConnection.java:84)
```

and, of course, much more...

Comment: What kind of certificate you're using ? a self-signed one or a CA generated certificate ?

Comment: It's a CA certificate from the site web service site we call.

Comment: Have you installed both the CA Root Certificate and your Certificate in the keystore ? (In order to "anchor" your certificate's chain of trust, you have to import the CA root certificate in the keystore )

Comment: Yes - this works under Netbeans, I'm just trying to get it to work using eclipse.

Comment: I have something that's working, please see comments below in @AbelRoussi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Of all you should know that Tomcat can use two different implementations of SSL :

> - The JSSE implementation provided as part of the Java runtime (since 1.4).
> - The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) implementation, or so called tomcat's "native library", which uses the OpenSSL engine by default
>     **(this is the best practice to follow)**.

---

What you're using now is the second implementation (I suppose that you have already installed it on your server), however the `SSLCertificateFile` should be the path to your certificate file and `SSLCertificateKeyFile`  the path to the key file. You should add another attribute called `SSLCertificateChainFile` that should point to the location of the CA Root Certificate.

Here is an example of APR Connectors Configuration from the [Tomcat Apache web site](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html)

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                 maxThreads="150"
                 enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                 acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                 SSLEnabled="true"
                 SSLCertificateFile="path/to/certificateFile/conf/localhost.crt"
                 SSLCertificateKeyFile="path/to/privatekeyFile/localhost.key" 
                 SSLPassword="keyStorePassw"
                 SSLCertificateChainFile="path/to/CAroot/certificate" keyAlias="youKeyAlias" 
                 SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2" />
```

---

**Otherwise** if you want to use the JSSE implementation here is an example of how to do it :

```
<Connector port="443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150"
 minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false" 
 disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" scheme="https" 
 secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" 
 sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="yourKeyAlias"
 keystoreFile="/path/to/yourKeystore/file.jks"
 keystorePass="keyStorePassw" />
```

> FYI : with **APR** the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKey`
>   attributes are used in place of the `keystoreFile` attribute used in
>   **JSSE** implementation.

For more information about configuring tomcat with SSL [Tomcat with SSL](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Comment: so, keystoreFile and keystorePass are for use with JSSE, and SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile and SSLPassword are for use with APR?

Comment: With **APR** the `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKey` attributes are used in place of the `keystoreFile` attribute used in **JSSE** implementations

Comment: It's still not working. If you're following and would like to help, please see the edit in the question above...

Comment: Well, I've got something that's working: I took the parameters fed on the Tomcat command line for Netbeans and put them in eclipse's Window / Preferences / Java / Installed JREs / Default VM arguments. Now the ewb service call that did fail is succeeding, and I can continue other debugging. But it would be nice to know how to accomplish this with server.xml, if someone has suggestions on that, I'm still interested.